# Go & VS Code Debugging | manually setting variable, not appearing in Locals, using Dlv

Tags: go, debugging, visual-studio-code, delve

I'm trying to "force" my `Go` system to behave in a particular manner to make my "testing" easier.

I have the following code snippet:

```golang
func SendTokenProcessFromModel(process model.Process) (*SendTokenProcess, error) {
    cdc := codec.New()
    var msgSend bank.MsgSend
    if err := cdc.UnmarshalJSON(process.RawMessage, &msgSend); err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("could not unmarshal a MsgSend: %w", err)
    }
    ...
}
```

In which I would like to set the `err` variable to `true` to force my function to stop and, as consequence, the action to fail.

I have come across 2x approaches to set a variable whilst debugging.

- [golang/vscode-go #1173](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/1173)
  Where they suggest that you set the variable using the `VARIABLES` tab in the debugger.

  I cannot do this as the `err` variable from my above snippet isn't present... the only variables present are the 3x others, namely: `cdc`, `process` & `msgSend` - assuming that our `Breakpoint` has been inserted at line "4": `if err := cdc...`
- [go-delve/delve #826](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/826)
  Where it is suggested to use the `dlv` CLI and to perform a command such as that outlined below:

> (dlv) `set err = "true"`

Due to the debugging session being instantiated by VS Code I cant access the `(dlv)` commands.
       I did try typing it directly into the `DEBUG CONSOLE` with no success, only error messages.
       I'm not saying this can't be done, just that I don't know how should it be possible.

From option 1 they also nention the below:

> `err := "true"`

But, again, not sure where, or how, to implement this.

Any help, guidance or support is appreciated as always.

Kind regards,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if the VSCode Debug Console has changed much, but here's what I worked out.

```
> set err=nil
Unable to evaluate expression: 1:5: expected 'EOF', found err
> set err nil
Unable to evaluate expression: 1:5: expected 'EOF', found err

> call err = nil
error nil
> call err = errors.New("Error")
> err
error(*errors.errorString) *{s: "Error"}
```

Non-spacing seems to be tolerated. I also had no problem with `call err=nil`.